# Method inside anonymous function inside map is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, es6-class

How does one invoke `handleButtonPress` inside the message map in this example React component?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {messages:["THANKS", "MERCI", "GRAZIE"]}
    this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this)
    this.handleButtonPress = this.handleButtonPress.bind(this)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.message}</Text>

        {
          this.state.messages.map(function(message, index){
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={function(){ this.handleButtonPress(message) }.bind(this) }>
                <Text>Press Me</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          })
        }

      </View>
    )
  }

  handleButtonPress(message){
    console.log("BUTTON WAS PRESSED WITH MESSAGE: " + message)
    this.myFunc(message)
  }

  myFunc(message){
    console.log("MY FUNCTION WAS CALLED")
    this.setState({message:message})
  }

}
```

Right now it's throwing: `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.handleButtonPress(message)')`. Why is that so?

Comment: Here again, `this` inside the `map` is undefined unless explicitly passed.

Comment: Wouldnt fat arrow function resolve this issue? `() =>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't bind a `this` context unless explicitly told to. From the documentation:

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `map`, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value. Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be passed for use as its this value.<sup>1</sup>

Since you never specify a `this` value, it is `undefined`, and doing thus the `this` that is bound to the anonymous function in `onPress` is `undefined`. That throws the error because there is no function `handleButtonPress` of `undefined`. This means you need to pass a `this` context to `map`, and from the documentation:

> **Syntax**
>
> `arr.map(callback[, thisArg])`

This will be applied like so:

```
{
    this.state.messages.map(function(message, index){
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={function(){ this.handleButtonPress(message) }.bind(this) }>
            <Text>Press Me</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }, this) //Notice the `this` here, this is the optional thisArg which is used as the `this` value in the callback.
}
```

The `this` is the class when passed to `map`. It will then be bound to `onPress`'s event handler (the anonymous function) and then call correctly. (**Note:** You should probably bind your methods once in the constructor because if you do it as you do now, a new method will be created every time the event is triggered.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, without a `thisArg` passed, the `this` value is determined as usual. Since `this` in regular functions is `window` (`undefined` in strict mode, which is default for classes), `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: amazing. thanks again @andrew-li . will mark correct.