# Why is onClick undefined inside my checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React.js and I'm creating a todo app.

The contents are roughly like this code.

```
class TodoValue extends React.Component{

  _onChange(){
    console.log("atacked");
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <List>
          {
            this.props.todos.map(function(todo, i){
              return <ListItem key={i} primaryText={todo.item} rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} leftCheckbox={<Checkbox onClick={this._onChange.bind(this)} />} />
            })
          }
        </List>
    );
  }
}
```

Why can not I find the `onChange` function in checkbox?

Input and button to update information are omitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method inside anonymous function inside map is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076995/method-inside-anonymous-function-inside-map-is-undefined)

Comment: @yuki nagahama did below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a declaration into your constructor:

```js
class TodoValue extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super()
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this)
  }
  _onChange(){
    console.log("atacked");
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <List>
          {
            this.props.todos.map(function(todo, i){
              return <ListItem key={i} primaryText={todo.item} rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} leftCheckbox={<Checkbox onClick={this._onChange.bind(this)} />} />
            })
          }
        </List>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice the added `constructor`.

You can take a look [here](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/) for a deeper explanation.

Comment: You need to add `super` to the `constructor` too

Comment: As far as I know, you only need `super` if you need to use `props` inside `constructor`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an `es6` arrow function

```
Checkbox onClick={()=> this._onChange.bind(this)}
```

Another approach would be to utilise React's built in `constructor` method. Here you should bind the `_onChange` method to the component.

```
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this)
  }
```

Then you can use

```
Checkbox onClick={this._onChange}
```